# What is the 'bootstrap node' when creating a monero wallet via the GUI?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod

Been awhile since I generated a wallet with the monero GUI and noticed this new section called 'bootstrap node' in the daemon settings section when creating a new wallet - what exactly is this?

Recently seen dEBRUYNE_1's [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/8rra06/proposal_make_the_gui_plugandplay_by_default_and/) regarding making the monero-GUI plug and play by running the daemon in the background whilst being connected to a temporary remote node. This bootstrap node already in the GUI sounds like it does just this, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

In the GUI, bootstrap node is a remote node to use *whilst also* syncing the blockchain. This is different to a straight up remote node in that using a remote node will not also sync the blockchain to local.

With regards to dEBRUYNE_1's reddit post, what is described is to *default* to using a bootstrap node and then *automatically* switch to local node when the blockchain has fully synced.

Comment: If the bootstrap node feature is utilized it will *always* automatically switch to the local node when the blockchain is fully synced, regardless of whether the user put in the remote node themselves or the remote node was specified by default.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE if this has been implement in latest GUI, where can I find the steps?

Comment: You can select `Simple mode (bootstrap)` in the setup process basically. This guide has a part about the three wallet modes available in the GUI: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/how-do-i-generate-a-ledger-monero-wallet-with-the-gui-monero-wallet-gui