# Monero GUI wallet address in combination with the Ledger Nano S

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, address, ledger, how-to

I installed the Monero GUI wallet on my laptop.

When I open the wallet and plug in my Ledger Nano S, I see an address on my Ledger Nano S which is different from the receiving address in the Monero GUI wallet.

What is the use of the Ledger Nano S in combination with the Monero GUI wallet?

Thanks.

Comment: The address displayed in the GUI should match the address displayed on the Ledger device. Are you perhaps looking at a subaddress in the GUI (one that starts with an `8`)?

Comment: My primary address on the Monery Gui wallet starts with 41 ; the one on my Ledger starts with 49.

Comment: type of Monero Gui wallet: GUI version: v0.13.0.4 (Qt 5.7.0)
Embedded Monero version: v0.13.0.4

Comment: Did you actually make sure to create a Ledger Monero wallet? If not, please see this guide -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/how-do-i-generate-a-ledger-monero-wallet-with-the-gui-monero-wallet-gui

Comment: You're using the correct version by the way.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that you have an integrated address, which is a composite address made of an underlying standard address and a short payment id, packed together. An integrated address can be split to recover both components, and some software, including Ledger, does so. So when you give it an integrated address, the address it displays will be the (shorter) standard address it recovered from it.