# "Error writing wallet from hardware device" on Monero GUI v0.14.0.0 and Ledger Nano S updated to firmware v 1.5.5 running on Windows 7

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

The error message at the bottom of the screen says: "failed to generate new wallet: Wrong Device Status : SW=6e00 (EXPECT=9000, MASK=ffff)"

This is with Monero GUI v0.14.0.0 and a Ledger Nano S updated to firmware v 1.5.5 on a Win 7 machine.

I tried the different solutions regarding the USB driver issues as prescribed on this answer in this thread: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/10182/10014

but it's still not working. When I plug in the Nano, the Device Manager screen updates and two new items are added: a 'Nano S' item under 'Other devices' and a 'USB Composite Device' under 'Universal Serial Bus controllers'.

I updated the driver on each one, right-clicking and searching for the driver under 'C:\Windows\winsxs' but still no dice. After the search, the message says "USB Composite Device - best driver already installed".

HarryTheHorse, the poster, mentions that the new item should show up under Smart card readers as a Microsoft Usbccid Smartcard Reader. I had the 'Smart Card' service turned off - I have a lot of unused services turned off for security reasons - but even with it on, the Device Manager does not show a 'Smart card readers' node and when I plug in the Nano and input the key, the same items show up and no 'Smart card reader' item.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Monero GUI v0.14.0.0]
[image: Device Manager screen]
[image]
Are there certain Windows Services or other processes that need to be turned on for the Monero GUI to work on the Ledger Nano S?

**UPDATE**

Comodo AV and it quarantined a bunch of monero components/exes, screenshot below. I'll try to redo the drag/drop and see if I can 'allow' install of these components.

[image]

Comment: Which version of the Ledger Monero app do you have installed?

Comment: On the Nano S device, it says 'App 1.2.2' and 'Spec 0.9.0' and on my Win 7 machine I have the ledger-live-desktop-1.9.1-win installed. Btw, I noticed that there is no 'monerod' file inside the Monero GUI folder. I just downloaded and unzipped the 'monero-gui-win-x64-v0.14.0.0.zip' file contents to a folder and double-clicked on 'monero-wallet-gui.exe'.

Comment: Thanks for the information. There should be a `monerod.exe` in the folder. Do you run active AV software (or do you have Windows Defender activated)?

Comment: I have Comodo Internet Security Premium and it did throw up some flags when I dragged/dropped the 'monero-gui-win-x64-v0.14.0.0' folder from the WinZip screen into Windows Explorer. I just opened Comodo and in the AV panel it had 5 'Detected Threats' and when I clicked on it, the next screen shows all these monero exes that are quarantined. I can post a screenshot on another comment. Should I un-quarantine them or just redo the drag/drop and somehow 'allow' these to be installed?

Comment: I disabled/turned off Comodo AV and even set the 'monero-gui-win-x64-v0.14.0.0.zip' file as a 'protected object' in Comodo but when I drag/drop, it still quarantines these monero exes.

Comment: Please try this guide -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10798/my-antivirus-av-software-blocks-quarantines-the-monero-gui-wallet-is-there

Comment: I set exclusions for two folder paths: one for the folder where the 'monero-gui-win-x64-v0.14.0.0.zip' file and the other for the 'monero-gui-v0.14.0.0' folder where I unzipped the contents to. Now, these exes are in there but I still get the same error when I try to create a hardware wallet in the Monero GUI. In Device Manager, the Nano S is still showing in 'Other devices' as missing its driver (yellow triangle with ! inside).

Comment: I looked at the Event Log > Applications and got this entry: 
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: PnPDriverNotFound
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: x64
P2: USB\VID_2C97&PID_0001&REV_0200&MI_02

Comment: I was able to add a Bitcoin account into the Nano using the 'Add account' button in Ledger Live, so perhaps the USB driver is working fine?

Comment: Can you please exactly follow the guide, i.e., create a new folder, whitelist the folder, re-extract the `.zip` file to the whitelisted folder? Thereafter, retry to generate a Ledger Monero wallet.

Comment: As mentioned, I did set exclusions for two folder paths: one for the folder where the 'monero-gui-win-x64-v0.14.0.0.zip' file and the other for the 'monero-gui-v0.14.0.0' folder where I unzipped the contents to. That didn't work so I just disabled Comodo AV and extracted the zip to the 'monero-gui-v0.14.0.0' folder, which created a second 'monero-gui-v0.14.0.0' folder in it. Anyway, I noticed when I opened the Monero app on the Nano, it was showing an XMR address, so instead of choosing 'Create new wallet' and chose 'Restore wallet' and it went thru. I'm now in the 'Account' screen.

Comment: So I'm now in the 'Account' screen, I've got some new questions: 1) do I go into Ledger Live and manage my Monero wallet from there or is most of the interaction with the Nano S done with the Monero desktop app? When I try to add an account in Ledger Live, the dropdown doesn't show Monero. Is there any integration between the two apps? 2) I notice at the bottom left of the it says 'Wallet blocks remaining' - do I have to wait until that progress bar becomes full before I can do anything with this wallet?

Comment: I'm wondering about the 'Wallet blocks remaining' progress bar - is it downloading the blockchain? My computer doesn't have that much space nor do I want to store it locally. I chose the 'Simple Mode' non-bootstrap option.

Comment: 1) Almost all interaction is done with the Monero desktop app. 2) Monero is not yet integrated in the Ledger Live wallet. 3). Yes, you have to wait until both status bars are at 100%. The initial wallet refresh only takes five to ten minutes though. If it takes longer, did you set a `Restore height` upon creating the `Restore` option? Otherwise it starts from zero, which is going to take a long time. If not set, please redo the process with a `Restore height` of `1840000`. And to clarify, it is not downloading the blockchain.

Comment: Please also check the guide I linked for more information -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/how-do-i-generate-a-ledger-monero-wallet-with-the-gui-monero-wallet-gui

Comment: dEBRUYNE, thank you for the clarification. On #2, I redid the process by starting at "Create a new wallet from hardware device" then "Restore a wallet", entered '1840000', then was prompted to create a password where I had to re-enter the password. I was concerned at this step that it would erase/remove the wallet I had already created with a 2nd account that had a different XMR address. When the wallet opened, it is missing that 2nd account I created.How do I recover that 2nd account or is that gone? Luckily, I didn't have any XMR in it yet.

Comment: dEBRUYNE, I sent some XMR to the 'Primary account' address yesterday and I haven't seen it yet. Do I see it with the initial wallet refresh you mentioned or not until both status bars are at 100%?

Comment: By simply recreating the account in the second wallet (accounts are deterministic). Both status bars have to be at 100%, yes. However, it should be relatively fast if you set `1840000` as restore / wallet creation height. Did you export the private view key? Also, which mode did you choose?

Comment: I chose 'Simple' mode and did not export the private key.

Comment: If I choose 'Create a new wallet from hardware' then choose 'Restore a wallet from device', I don't see that 2nd account/wallet/address that I created previously. But if I choose 'Open a wallet from file' then browse to the .keys file, the wallet get restored with that 2nd account/wallet/address that I created. I confused as to which one I should do and what the differences are with either. I do see that with the 'Open a wallet from file' option, it doesn't allow me to set the 'Restore height'. Perhaps I should start a new question for this?

Comment: Not exporting the private *view* (not spend) key drastically impacts performance, i.e., the wallet refresh will be obnoxiously slow. I'd personally recommend to export the private view key. If you create a second / account in the 'new' wallet, it will be the same as in the 'old' wallet. Thus, it does not really matter which wallet file you use.