# Why are the Monero GUI components (exes) flagged by AV as malware?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I was able to get around this by disabling my Comodo AV but it makes me wonder what code is/are in these exes/binaries that is making the AV see them as malware? I code, so I'll be fine discussing this at the code level (specific functions, calls to the OS, etc.)

Comment: For visibility purposes, a guide that contains a work around can be found here: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10798/my-antivirus-av-software-blocks-quarantines-the-monero-gui-wallet-is-there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because they contain mining code (should you want to mine). Also because we don't code sign with a commercial certificate from Microsoft.

Comment: Does the mining code match the profile or signature of a botnet virus component, one that runs a process that uses processing cycles? As for the cert, I understand that a non-commercial cert (not from a CA or Trusted Root CA) will get flagged.

Comment: Probably. Only the AV vendor could confirm.