# Why does my pc not connect to Monero download page?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, installation

I am trying to download Monero 64-bit installer for windows from the following page https://downloads.getmonero.org/gui/win64install

but I get the following error when I click on the link.

```
This site can’t be reacheddownloads.getmonero.org refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have tried accessing the download page from several different browsers and I get the same result.  The internet connection is fine and I don't know what a proxy is and I don't know how to use the firewall to check if that is the problem. Please advise, thanks.

EDIT: I have found another Monero download site. Are there 2 sites or is one a fake site?  https://downloads.monero.org/monero-win-x64-v0.11.1.0.zip is the second site. But when i click on this page I get a different error:

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from downloads.monero.org (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Help improve Chrome security by sending URLs of some pages you visit, limited system information, and some page content to Google. Privacy policy
```

Comment: monero[dot]org is not the official website. I'd thus strongly advise to avoid it (and definitely do not download anything off of it). With respect to not being able to reach getmonero.org (the official website), are you running active AV (AntiVirus) software?

Comment: I have tried disabling the antivirus with no result.

Comment: Can you try the Github link? https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/releases/tag/v0.15.0.1

Comment: I tried to download direct from github but when i run the program my antivirus detects a threat "We've moved monero-blockchain-import.exe to your quarantine because it was infected with Win64:Malware-gen."  Is this a genuine threat? how should i proceed now?

Comment: actually the antivirus is detecting lots of threats and putting all the files in quarantine.

Comment: It is a false positive as long as you properly verified the SHA256 hash. I'd recommend to utilize this guide in order to solve the AV issue: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10798/my-antivirus-av-software-blocks-quarantines-the-monero-gui-wallet-is-there

Comment: Antivirus makers typically do slapdash work here, and will blindly blacklist anything that looks like existing malware. Since some malware includes monero mining code, they crank up the false positives to minimize the false negatives. Since Monero doesn't have that many users, they don't care much about the collateral damage.

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact problem, had to turn off my AV and it fixed it ty :)