# Why did the Monero GUI fail to generate a new wallet with the Ledger?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, windows, ledger, issue

I just tried to create a wallet but in the window, after choosing the location for the wallet file, I get this message:

```
failed to generate new wallet: Unable to enumerate device 11415:11415: NULL device
```

The system is Windows 10 64 bit.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Edit: Monero Logfile:

```
2019-07-27 20:06:07.430 20860   ERROR   device.io   src/device/device_io_hid.cpp:82 Unable to enumerate device 11415:11415: NULL device
2019-07-27 20:06:38.169 20860   ERROR   device.io   src/device/device_io_hid.cpp:82 Unable to enumerate device 11415:11415: NULL device
2019-07-27 20:07:12.125 20860   ERROR   device.io   src/device/device_io_hid.cpp:82 Unable to enumerate device 11415:11415: NULL device
2019-07-27 20:08:34.524 20860   ERROR   device.io   src/device/device_io_hid.cpp:82 Unable to enumerate device 11415:11415: NULL device
2019-07-27 20:08:37.113 20860   ERROR   device.io   src/device/device_io_hid.cpp:82 Unable to enumerate device 11415:11415: NULL device
2019-07-27 20:18:05.699 20860   ERROR   frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:371   Trying to close non existing wallet  QObject(0x0)
2019-07-27 20:18:05.764 20860   WARN    frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:367   External WM_DESTROY received for  TipItem_QMLTYPE_212(0x1934ff20) , parent:  QWindow(0x0) , transient parent:  ApplicationWindow_QMLTYPE_228_QML_284(0x9e22370, name="appWindow")
2019-07-27 20:18:05.774 20860   WARN    frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:367   External WM_DESTROY received for  DaemonConsole_QMLTYPE_8(0x1a7fc690) , parent:  QWindow(0x0) , transient parent:  ApplicationWindow_QMLTYPE_228_QML_284(0x9e22370, name="appWindow")
```

Comment: Have you followed [this guide](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/9902/7493)?

Comment: Are you sure that your Ledger is unlocked and in the Monero app?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/5955)

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm new here ;)

Answer (score 2):

It seems a problem related to Windows USB controller, you can try using the [Hardware and Devices troubleshooter](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/windows-10-hardware-and-system-trouble-shooter/39029d76-d6eb-4b84-82ac-2016686e44d7) to fix the problem. It checks for common issues and makes sure that any new device or hardware attached to your computer was installed correctly.

Also, if you are using your Ledger connected to a USB 3.0 port, you can try to use it in USB 2.0 port, or vice-versa.