# Monero GUI isn't letting me create wallet from Ledger (monero-wallet-gui)

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I've seen [How do I generate a Ledger Monero wallet with the GUI (monero-wallet-gui)?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/how-do-i-generate-a-ledger-monero-wallet-with-the-gui-monero-wallet-gui) but the `Create Wallet From Hardware` option isn't appearing for me.

I've followed the steps in the the linked guide.

- the monero ledger app is installed and open
- ledger live is closed
- I've opened the monero GUI

GUI version v0.11.1.0

Ledger nano S, monero app v1.7.4

Firmware updated

Once I select the language there is no option to create a new wallet from hardware.
[image]
Where do I go from here?

GUI hashes verified

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a forgotten old version of the monero wallet from 2017 which wasn't overwritten when I installed the latest one.  Everything is working now