# Can I use BOTH a Trezor T and Ledger S with the same Monero-GUI wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger, trezor, mobile

Trying to wrap my head around this. I have both a Trezor T and Ledger S.

I use the same seed on both devices as a sort of redundancy.

I just set up the Trezor with Monero's GUI. Worked great, although not having to generate a new seed kind of threw me off (but I now understand the Trezor handles).

Can I also set up the Ledger S, using the same process with the same wallet on my computer? If this is a bad idea, just let me know.

Juggling like 7 different wallets and it's becoming pretty confusing. Most of my funds are in the shared Trezor/Ledger "seed", but I do have other various hot wallets for on-the-go use, since I don't carry my Trezor/Ledger around with me all the time.

Any insight on all of this?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can actually use the Ledger to open the Trezor Monero wallet (even though the underlying private spend key (mnemonic seed) is the same), as by setting up the Trezor Monero wallet, the Trezor code / logic will be used for the wallet. You can, however, set up a separate Ledger Monero wallet, which should have the same address. See: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/how-do-i-generate-a-ledger-monero-wallet-with-the-gui-monero-wallet-gui